# IndexError while performing argsort operation on an array

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, index-error

I have 2 Numpy arrays of length 107952899.

1. `a = []`
2. `b = []`

I want to find the indices inside the array `a` which are greater than 20. I am storing that result in a variable `c`:

```
c = np.where(a > 20)
```

Then by using `c` (which stores the indices), I want to find the values inside the numpy array `b` with respect to the corresponding indices. I store that in `d`:

```
d = b[c]
```

Then, I want the top `n` maximum elements in `d` with the actual indices. With those indices, I will be performing further calculations.

```
d.argsort([-N])[::-1]
```

I tried using `argsort`, but I get the following error:

```
IndexError: Invalid index to scalar value
```

So, to summarize, I have 2 numpy arrays. In the first array, I have to filter the values which are greater than 20. Then, I have to find the respective values in the second array by using the filtered indices of the first array. After that, I have to sort the second array in descending order and get those indices for further calculations.

I tried the above method by introducing those arrays in a Pandas DataFrame, and while it works fine, I prefer to do it directly.

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: array([0.3,0.3,0.3,.................,1.2, 1.2, 1.2])@EdekiOkoh

Comment: From the output of d it looks like it is a 1-D array. However when you use:

    'd.argsort([-N])[::-1]'

You are trying to index it as a 2-D array which is giving the error. Can you go into more detail about what you want to do on d? Do you just want the index of the n max elements in that array?

Comment: What's the purpose of the `[-N]` parameter of `argsort`?  Why didn't you use `d.argsort()`?

Comment: But isn't the `c` returned by `np.where` a tuple? I don't think you can directly index with `c`

Comment: argsort is slow anyways especially given the fact his list have a length of 107952899. [numpy.argpartition](https://gist.github.com/nishio/016976c9db6fdff7ea568e31861b1549) would be the better method to use.

Comment: @yatu, The index for an array can be a tuple.  The tuple returned by `np.where` can be used to index an array of the same size, e.g. `a[ np.where(a>20)]` is valild.

Comment: For more info : a array - Speed values , b array - brake values, I have another array called Time.(Speed & Brake values with respect to the equal time interval).In such a way, 3 arrays each of length 107952899. Assume these three values in a pandas DF. Now i want the filter speed value above 20 km/hr. So I will get the respective brake values in the brake column.Now i want the maximum brake Value & Its indices. With that, i will generate a plot between brake Vs Speed keeping my maximum brake indices as a center point. I tried it in pandas but lack of memory i want to do it in Numpy.

Comment: Yes but arent the arrays uni-dimensional? @hpaulj

Comment: @yafu, `np.where(a)` returns a tuple of arrays, one for each dimension of `a`.

Comment: Yes I know. But I understood that these arrays had only 1 dimension. Misunderstood otherwise. Just curious

Comment: Tested solution below. Your issue is you were trying to use argsort as if d was a 2-D array

Comment: yes arrays are uni Dimentional @hpaulj

Comment: @yatu, If `a` is uni Dimensional, then `np.where(a>30)` will be a 1 element tuple.  That tuple can still be used to index `a` (or `b`).  `a[ np.where(a>30)[0])` would also work, but the `[0]` is not needed.

Comment: Gotcha @hpaulj you're right

Answer (score 1):

**Try using something like this:**

First convert your array d into a numpy array if it is not already one

```
d_arr = np.asarray(d)
```

Then you can use the **[numpy.argpartition](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html)** method to get the indexes of the n largest values

```
idx = np.argpartition(d_arr, -N)[-N:]
```

To get the index of the N largest elemnts in your array. Then you can do

```
d_arr[idx]
```

To return what those elements are.

The Test I used to confirm that this method works:

```
a = np.array([1,2,4,6,7,8,9,9,9,7,4])
idx = np.argpartition(a, -5)[-5:]

print(idx)
[4 5 8 7 6]

print(a[idx])
[7 8 9 9 9]
```

For larger arrays, I would stick with the **[numpy.argpartition](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html)** method over the **[numpy.argsort](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html)** based on the comparison test **[here](https://gist.github.com/nishio/016976c9db6fdff7ea568e31861b1549)** since it shows **[numpy.argpartition](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html)** is twice as fast as **[numpy.argsort](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html)**.

Comment: I was tempted to say suggesting `argpartition` was an unnecessarily advanced step, when he couldn't even get `argsort` right.  But the use `[-N]` suggests he might actually have had `argpartition` in mind.

Comment: I think he wanted argpartition but came across argsort first simply because of SEO (argsort has been around longer for these type of problems).

Comment: How does argpartition works in place for argsort ? i read the documentation even after i cannot get a clear image....(both are same),

Comment: Ask another question on stack and I can give you the answer. A real answer is too long for comments

Comment: @EdekiOkoh am not getting the correct answer what i required.
for example if i take one index value and try a[idx], its value is not less than 20, also its b[idx] value is not the value i expected. I believe after finding d = b[c] it changes to a fresh array with new indices...But i needed Original Indices ???
Hope you understand..

Comment: Because you are not using np.where and tracking the incidences, you are only returning the results. argpartition will get you the answer you need but you will need to incorporate your assumptions into it also